# I am using firebase to delete images, but they are uploaded but not deleted.(using react,typescript,firebase)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

```
const ProfileModal = ({ children, onClick }: ModalCloseProps) => {
  const [attachment, setAttachment] = useState<string | ArrayBuffer | null>(
    null,
  );
  const fileRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const storage = getStorage();
  const uniqueKey = new Date().getTime();

  const saveToFirebaseStorage = (file: File) => {
    const newName = file.name
      .replace(/[~`!#$%^&*+=\-[\]\\';,/{}()|\\":<>?]/g, '')
      .split(' ')
      .join('');

    const metaData = {
      contentType: file.type,
    };

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${newName + uniqueKey}`);

    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metaData);
    uploadTask.on(
      'state_changed',
      snapshot => {
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(downloadurl => {
          console.log(`Done:${downloadurl}`);
        });
      },
    );
  };

  const deleteFile = (file: File) => {
    const newName = file.name
      .replace(/[~`!#$%^&*+=\-[\]\\';,/{}()|\\":<>?]/g, '')
      .split(' ')
      .join('');
    const desertRef = ref(storage, `images/${newName + uniqueKey}`);
    deleteObject(desertRef)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`delete success`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`delete ${error}`);
      });
  };

  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {
      target: { files },
    } = event;

    if (!files) return null;
    const theFile = files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (onLoadEvent: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
      const { currentTarget } = onLoadEvent;
      if (currentTarget instanceof FileReader) {
        const { result } = currentTarget;
        if (result !== null) setAttachment(result);
      }
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(theFile);
    saveToFirebaseStorage(theFile);
  };

  const handleFileButtonClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>,
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fileRef.current?.click();
  };

  return (
    <Modal>
      <PreviewOuterImage src={attachment?.toString()} />
      <PreviewImageContainer>
        <PreviewInnerImage></PreviewInnerImage>
        {attachment ? (
          <img src={attachment.toString()} alt={attachment.toString()} />
        ) : null}
      </PreviewImageContainer>
      <Form>
        <ImageMessageContainer>
          <ImageMessageInput type="text" placeholder="Please Upload." />
          <Label htmlFor="file-input">
            <IoMdCloudUpload className="cloud" />
          </Label>
          <ImageInputUpload
            onChange={onChange}
            id="file-input"
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
          />
        </ImageMessageContainer>
        <button onClick={handleFileButtonClick}>Upload</button>
        <button onClick={deleteFile}>Delete</button>
      </Form>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

The onChange function is activated when `IoMdCloudUpload` (icon) is clicked.

and When the Upload button is clicked, the `handleFileButtonClick` function is called, which then calls `saveToFirebaseStorage` to work.

When I upload a photo using the handleFileButtonClick function, the photo is uploaded to Firebase, but when I click the Delete button, it does not work properly and cannot be deleted. Is my code in the deleteFile function wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors when deleting the files? Also can you `console.log(newName, uniqueKey)` and ensure the file does exist in the storage (with same file extension)?

Comment: Oh right, I get a typescript error in the onClick function attached to Delete.

`Type '(file: File) => void' cannot be assigned to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  The 'file' and 'event' parameters have incompatible types.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is missing lastModified, name, webkitRelativePath, size and 5 other properties of type 'File'`

Also, I checked newName and uniqueKey, I see an error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I don't know why name is undefined

Comment: Also,I checked if the file exists in the deleteFile function, and undefined came out. I don't know how to fix this part.